# Can you explain the behavior of this snake?

Tags: zoology, ethology, behaviour, fruit, snake

[image: p[![][image: ][1]][image: ]]I just saw this video in which a snake is swallowing grapes. 
 (["Whip snake eating grapes"](https://youtu.be/CZI3_4EBZW4?t=180)).
In the video, the snake just doesn't eat but goes on to swallow 2-3 grapes.
I did some research on the internet and in "bio stack exchange" but only to find that "snakes are obligate carnivores", which simply means they don't have the body mechanism to digest a vegetarian diet.
My guess is that it mistook the grapes for a prey due to the smell coming from the grapes, which may be left there by a rodent or any other organism the snake feeds on. 
Can you provide a possible explanation for this snake's behavior? Regards

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the site!  Please don't just include links; they break with time.  Describe the behaviour, including pictures & figures as needful, with the link for reference.  Please [edit] so that this question would make sense even if the link were to break.  Thanks!

Comment: @rotaredom Hello, I didn't know about that. Made the changes.

Comment: Maybe that's an egg-eating snake that confused the fruits with eggs?

Comment: @Roland : Maybe, but my guess is that its something to do with the smell/odor of the grapes. Either the pray (like a small mouse) left its smell on the grapes or certain smell released by the grapes caught the attention of this snake. But I'm not sure..

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Please take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site and [edit] your question accordingly. In particular, the title of your question should be clear and as specific as possible — the current title unhelpful since you've already provide clear evidence that yes they can. ——— We also encourage you to do some research on your own and then, informed by what you have learned, ask any questions you still have (ideally with references to reliable sources). Thanks! 

Comment: @tyersome Hello, thanks for the info. I made the changes to the post. I hope they are in alignment with the Biology.SE format. I also hope that the title and the content are more comprehensive to the reader.

Comment: You can convert up to 30 sec of a youtube video to a GIF file using gifs.com. If the resulting gif is > 2mb in size, then I recommend using ezgif.com to "optimize" it (e.g., cropping, reducing quality or size, etc.). In any event, it'd be best to have some stable evidence of your video on Bio.SE, which you can do by uploading the gif in the question editor. You can sill link to your original video, but inclusion of the animation on our site ensures that even if your youtube link dies, this post will still be "complete" and useful to someone in the future. Please [edit] accordingly. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right, snakes rely on scent to capture their prey. The fact that snakes are carnivores may be the one constant among all snake species; absolutely none feed even partially on plant matter. So if plant matter is found in their feces, it must have gotten there accidentally.

Here, check out this [post](https://steemit.com/science/@herpetologyguy/why-don-t-any-snakes-eat-plants), which answers your question perfectly:

> In most instances, these have been attributed to accidental ingestion, perhaps eaten with a prey item or mistaken for prey by scent...One interesting case was discovered by Harvey Lillywhite in a study published in the journal BioScience in 2008. Studying the scavenging behavior of pitvipers in the intertidal zone, Lillywhite observed cottomouth droppings that were composed almost entirely of seaweed. This was too much plant material to have been eaten secondarily or by accident, and he suspected that there was some other cause for the snakes to be eating it (it certainly wasn't for energy as the seaweed was passing through completely undigested. Lillywhite wondered if it was possible the snakes were feeding on seaweed simply because it smelled like fish. An interesting laboratory experiment proved their hypothesis correct; they offered various plants to cottonmouths, some with fish and others without. The plants without fish were investigated by the snakes, but ultimately left uneaten. Those that did contain fish were quickly devoured. Even when the fish was removed, the snakes ate the remaining seaweed simply because it smelled like their prey!

Comment: Thanks. The blog post, as well as the research (mentioned in the blog) conducted on such behaviors of snakes, answered my question very well. Thanks again.

Answer (score -3):

I've seen a deer eating a live bird so a snake eating grapes doesn't surprise me.
My philosophy is that animals know better than us what they are doing, so if someone is mistaking it's probably us.

Anyway, my answer would be that this snake needs a substance (perhaps the acid since it's unrip) contained in those grapes, if it's not for feeding then it's for healing.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Please take the [tour] and then consult the help pages for additional advice on [Answer] effectively on this site. In particular, answers are expected to be based on facts rather than speculations. You are also more likely to get a positive response to an answer if you include supporting references to reputable sources. Without this your answer is indistinguishable from opinion. Thank you! 

Comment: an herbivore eating meat and a carnivore eating plants are very different, all herbivores can digest meat, meat is just far easier for an animal to digest.